# Showing Function is Measurable

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory

I'm struggling with the following problem: Let $(X, \mathcal{X})$ and $(Y, \mathcal{Y})$ be measure spaces, and suppose that for each $x \in X$ there is a probability measure $\nu_x$ on $(Y, \mathcal{Y})$. Assume also that for any $B \in \mathcal{Y}$, $\nu_x(B)$ is, as a function of $X$, measurable $\mathcal{X}$.
I am trying to show that for $E \in \mathcal{X} \times \mathcal{Y}$, we have that $\nu_x(\{ y : (x, y) \in E \})$ is measureable $\mathcal{X}$.

I'm trying to show that, if we consider the function $f(x) = \nu_x(\{ y : (x, y) \in E \})$ for a given $E$, that the inverse image $f^{-1}((-\infty, a))$ is measurable. This is clear if $a$ is negative or $a$ is greater than $1$, but I don't see how to deal with the case that $0 < a < 1$.

Comment: wtf is $B$?....

Comment: @mathworker21 Sorry, $B$ is any set in $\mathcal{Y}$.

Comment: Why does it follow that $\nu_x(\{y : (x,y) \in E\}) $ is measurable? Here the set $B$ would be $\{y : (x,y) \in E\}$, which depends on $x$.

Comment: @mathworker21 That's the claim I'm trying to show. I edited the question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 3):

If $E=A\times B$ then $\nu_x\{y:(x,y)\in E\}=\nu_x(B) I_A(x)$ which is measurable. Show that the collection of all $E \in \mathcal X \times \mathcal Y$ for which $\nu_x\{y:(x,y)\in E\}$ is measurable is a sigma algebra and finish the proof.

Comment: (+1) very nice :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! A quick clarification: why do I need to do the second step of showing that the collection is a $\sigma$-algebra?

Comment: To prove measurability for all $E$ in the product sigma algebra you first verify it for measurable rectangles. But the sigma algebra has lots of sets which are not of the type $A \times B$. To prove the result for all $E$ you have to use the argument I have given. Note that $\mathcal X \times \mathcal Y$ is a misleading notation and it does not stand for just product sets $A \times B$. It is the sigma algebra generated by these.

Comment: I understand the point about the rectangles, but I'm also a bit confused. Don't I need to show that it is measurable with respect to the original sigma algebra, not a new sigma algebra? How do I go about showing that it is measurable $\mathcal{X}$?

Comment: Measurability of $f$ is with respect to $\mathcal X$.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm new to this and I still don't see what you mean. Could you expound a bit on the second sentence, and the steps that would complete the proof?

Comment: I would like to help but it is not clear to me as to how familiar you are with sigma algebras. If you are new to sigma algebras then you should come back to this a little later.